# Dependent Origination in terms of conventional truth or teaching (Vohara Desana) and Ultimate truth or teaching (Paramattha Desana)?

Tags: theravada

It appears many of my doubts and questions about Buddhism is the result of not being able to marry the teaching of conventional truth and the ultimate truth. For instance, when we take Jati in Dependent Origination, in terms of Vohara Desana it applies to the physical rebirth of a person. However, in the ultimate sense, there is no person then who is re-born? Ultimate sense what is re-born is the attachment, aversion, and ignorance.
We can apply this duality to all 12 links of DO.
Actually, this dilemma is very similar to the problem of scientists who are trying to understand the relation between the universe and the atoms.

Does Dependent Origination cover both conventional teaching and Ultimate teaching?

Comment: I have posted the same question in Dhamma Wheel.https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=34227

Answer (score 2):

The Buddha did not teach Dependent Origination has a "conventional truth". Dependent Origination, as taught by the Buddha, only explains the arising of the ideas of "beings" ("satta") which cause the arising of suffering.

> In the course of the future there will be monks who
>   won't listen when discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep,
>   deep in their meaning, transcendent, connected with emptiness — are
>   being recited. They won't lend ear, won't set their hearts on knowing
>   them, won't regard these teachings as worth grasping or mastering. But
>   they will listen when discourses that are literary works — the works
>   of poets, elegant in sound, elegant in rhetoric, the work of
>   outsiders, words of disciples — are recited. They will lend ear and
>   set their hearts on knowing them. They will regard these teachings as
>   worth grasping & mastering. In this way the disappearance of the
>   discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their
>   meaning, transcendent, connected with emptiness — will come about.